# Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' Swift

Tags: swift

I keep getting - 6 Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' after "lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
   
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1
    lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    lpgr.delegate = self
    self.colVw.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

    @objc func handleLongPress(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureReconizer.state != UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            //When lognpress is start or running
        }
        else {
            //When lognpress is finish
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: If what you posted is exactly your code, it's probably complaining about executable statements existing outside of a function.

Comment: i have edited the code theres is none executable statements existing outside jet i still get this error .. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are wrong, there are several lines of executable statements outside a function or an init

Answer (score 3):

As @Philip Mills pointed out, there are executable statements outside of a function.
Here is a example:

```
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1
    lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    lpgr.delegate = self
    self.colVw.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

All of these are *executable* statements because they can be executed. Move these inside a function.